# Customize search filter .NET Core 6

Tags: entity-framework, .net-6.0

I am creating a project in .NET 6 with Entity Framework. The idea is to create a search engine that filters by expiration date, for that I had thought that if the expiration date is less than today it should return an expired certificate, otherwise, it should filter the records it finds

For that I made a function in the controller, which I tested manually assigning dates and everything seems to be fine. My problem is that I don't know how to save the date into a variable to be able to use it in the if condition, I feel a little confused and my question is, am I doing it right? Should I try another way? Or if it's ok, how can I get the date to assign to a variable?

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

    IQueryable<Personal> personal = _db.Personal;

    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2023, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    if (searchString != null)
    {
        if (date1 < today)
        {
            return View("Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
            personal = personal.Where(s => s.Rut!.Contains(searchString));  
        }              
    }

    return View(await personal.ToListAsync());          
}
```

I also tried creating these variables to be able to assign the date in the if, but when debugging the date it does not take the value and leaves it by default (01/01/0001 0:00:00).

I would really appreciate your help, thanks

```
Personal p = new Personal();
var fecha = p.FechaCertificado;
```

Comment: Will the date come from user input?

Comment: I create the date in the person model and there is a date input only for when a new record is created

Comment: How were you testing the controller? Are you just pasting the URL in your browser? Or do you already have a UI? If you already have a UI, please also post your UI code.